# sorted queue using liked list

Tags: sorting, linked-list, queue

I have to implement a queue using a linked list while doing enqueue I have to sort the queue in descending order and print it, dequeue is normal

I called the sort function every time I do enqueue, I get some error in the sort function
error:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVwri.png

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.front = self.rear = None

    class Node:
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data  # Data part of the node
            self.next = None  # Next reference of the node
    def print(self):
        curr = self.front
        string = ''
        while curr:
            string += '|' + str(curr.data) + '|'
            curr = curr.next
        print(string)

    def is_Empty(self):
        return self.front == None

    def sort(self):
        curr = self.front
        while curr.next:
            if curr.data < curr.next.data:
                temp = curr.next
                curr.next = curr
                curr = temp
            curr = curr.next

    def Enqueue(self, item):
        temp = Node(item)
        if self.rear == None:
            self.front = self.rear = temp
            return
        self.rear.next = temp
        self.rear = temp

    def Dequeue(self):
        if self.is_Empty():
            return("The Queue is empty!")
        temp = self.front
        self.front = temp.next
        if (self.front == None):
            self.rear = None
            return self.rear

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    while (True):
        choice = int(input("1. Enqueue\n2. Dequeue\n3. Exit\n"))
        if (choice == 1):
            data_ll = int(input("Please enter the data: "))
            q.Enqueue(data_ll)
            q.sort()
            q.print()
        elif (choice == 2):
            q.Dequeue()
            q.print()
```

Comment: The interfaces are inconsistent. Dequeue returns a node, while Enqueue accepts a value (item). My guess is sort is to be limited to using enqueue and dequeue operations, but the current code appears to be an attempt to sort a linked list, which is a different container than a queue. You may want to add a size (number of elements in queue) function (the code would need to keep track of the number of nodes in the queue). A merge sort can be implemented if a second queue is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error was in creating a node in Enqueue function. The inner class function should be called as self.Node  and the other thing was sorting function doesn't sort.
Given below is the fixed code

````
class Queue:
    

    class Node:
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data  # Data part of the node
            self.next = None  # Next reference of the node
            
            
    def __init__(self):
        self.front = self.rear = None        
    def print(self):
        curr = self.front
        string = ''
        while curr:
            string += '|' + str(curr.data) + '|'
            curr = curr.next
        print(string)

    def is_Empty(self):
        return self.front == None
        
    def get_size(self):
        
        temp = self.front 
        count = 0 
        while (temp):
            count += 1
            temp = temp.next
        return count

    def sort(self):
        
        # print("[",curr.data,"]")
        count=self.get_size()
        while(count):  
            curr = self.front
            while (curr and curr.next):
                if curr.data > curr.next.data:
                    temp=curr.data
                    curr.data=curr.next.data
                    curr.next.data=temp
              
                curr = curr.next
            count-=1    

    def Enqueue(self, item):
        temp = self.Node(item)
        if self.rear == None:
            self.front = self.rear = temp
            return
        self.rear.next = temp
        self.rear = temp

    def Dequeue(self):
        if self.is_Empty():
            return("The Queue is empty!")
        temp = self.front
        self.front = temp.next
        if (self.front == None):
            self.rear = None
            return self.rear

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    while (True):
        choice = int(input("1. Enqueue\n2. Dequeue\n3. Exit\n"))
        if (choice == 1):
            data_ll = int(input("Please enter the data: "))
            q.Enqueue(data_ll)
            q.sort()
            q.print()
        elif (choice == 2):
            q.Dequeue()
            q.print()
```
````